# How to share Request/Respons class between Android and AWS Lambda

Tags: java, android, aws-lambda

With an Android app that uses AWS Lambda, the Request/Response classes appear in both sides under the different modules of the same project. If not shared, the two classes will appear in 2 places:

```
.
├── app
│   └── src
│       ├── main
│       │   └── java
│       │       └── com
│       │           └── myapp
│       │              ├── Request.java
│       │              └── Response.java
│       └── test
├── lambda
│   └── src
│       └── main
│           └── java
│               └── com
│                   └── myapp
│                      ├── Request.java
│                      └── Response.java
```

The first idea to share these classes is to add `lambda` module as a dependency to the `app` module, by adding the following to `app/build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(":lambda")
```

But that wouldn't work, since

- `lambda` project depends on the AWK SDK
- `app` project depends on AWS Mobile SDK

and they are not compatible with each other (both provides some same classes under the same package).

The second method is to use symbolic links, linking the Request/Response classes so that they appear in both modules (under the same package of course), which works. Is it the proper way to do it though?

Answer (score 2):

I would create a third area, specifically for "common" code.  Something like:

```
├── app
│   └── src
│       ├── main
│       │   └── java
│       │       └── com
│       │           └── myapp
│       └── test
│
├── lambda
│   └── src
│       └── main
│           └── java
│               └── com
│                   └── myapp
├── common
│    └── src
│       └── main
│           └── java
│               └── com
│                   └── myapp
│                      ├── Request.java
│                      └── Response.java
```

and then have the common library be a dependency for both the Android and the Lambda code.

Comment: Thanks and I'm using what you suggested for now. I was hoping there is a way to do so without spliting the `com.myapp` package into too many modules and not creating a new `build.gradle` and maintain it. Maybe something like DependencyInject, but so far this works.